# @rollup/plugin-json with typescript not working

Tags: json, typescript, rollup

I have a valid appsettings.json file (according to jsonlint.com), I've set the tsconfig resolveJsonModule option to true.  I'm importing @rollup/plugin-json and I've tried calling it at every position in the plugins chain.  But I always get:

```
(!) Plugin json: Could not parse JSON file
appsettings.json
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
appsettings.json (2:10)
```

So the plugin is firing (I think), but it can't parse the file, which seems to be valid.  Rollup config looks like this:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import dev from 'rollup-plugin-dev';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';


// Loaders for non-ts/js file types
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

console.log(`Node env is ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
// console.debug(process);
let isDevEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'; 
let useMsw = process.env.USE_MSW;

const extensions = ['.cjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css', '.png'];
// const intro = useMsw
//     ? 'global = window; window.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV; window.USE_MSW = true'
//     : 'global = window; window.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV; window.USE_MSW = false';

const intro = `global = window; window.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV; ${useMsw ? 'window.USE_MSW = true;' : ''}`;
export default {
    input: [
        'src/index.tsx'
    ],
    output: {
        intro: intro,
        file: './dist/bundle.js',
        format: 'es',
        sourcemap: isDevEnv,
        inlineDynamicImports: true,

    },
    plugins: [
        postcss({}),
        resolve({
            extensions: extensions,
            browser: true
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript(),
        replace({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        }),
        image(),
        copy({
            targets: [
                {src: './src/index.html', dest: './dist/'},
                {src: './src/mockServiceWorker.js', dest: './dist/'}
            ],
            verbose: true
        }),
        isDevEnv && dev('dist', {
            host: 'localhost'
        }),
        json(),
    ]
};
```

tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "ES2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "declaration.d.ts",
    "src/components/TabularVIew/GridContainer/hooks"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and the actual json file looks like this:

```
{
   "HUB_URL": "theHubUrl",
  "AUTH_ENDPOINT": "https://localhost:44330/API/Dispatch/Authentication/v1.0/authenticate",
  "POSITION_ENDPOINT": "https://localhost:44330/API/Dispatch/Data/v1.0/position",
  "SUMMARY_ENDPOINT": "https://localhost:44330/API/Dispatch/Data/v1.0/summaries",
  "GLOBAL_TLM": 1,
  "PERIOD_LENGTH_MINUTES": 30,  
  "EFA_BLOCKS": [
    [23,0,1,2],
    [3,4,5,6],
    [7,8,9,10],
    [11,12,13,14],
    [15,16,17,18],
    [19,20,21,22]
  ]
}
```

and the rollup output is this:

```
(!) Plugin json: Could not parse JSON file
appsettings.json
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
appsettings.json (2:10)
```

Pretty frustrating because on one line it says 'plugin json can't parse', then the next log line tells me I need plugin json???. Invalid file, file not found, plugin not installed, these I could understand.  Possibly a clash between tsc and the plugin. Out of ideas..
Suggestions welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: I just pointed my import at my package.json and it build fine.  If i cut and paste the package.json into myFile.json, it fails with the above error.  Both the package.json and myFile.json are at the same folder level.  Utterly confused.  I also went into the source file of the plugin and added `console.log(json)` after the 'Could not parse' error, and it logs `{
  "thing": "a value"
}`

Comment: I tried @Mark D answer below and it did not work because I added the `.json` extension to the list of babel extensions. When I removed the extension from there, it worked

Comment: I have the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891917/vite-js-output-json-to-separate-assets-folder

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that can be the json file encoding is `utf8withbom`. Try to encode the file as `utf8`.

Comment: strangely this answer helped. Thanks! And shame on us, developers, for creating such fragile software...

Comment: and how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but the behaviour appears to be linked to some aggressive caching. Either by npm or typescript.  I opened up the project in vscode, hosed node_modules, ran npm install, usual drill.. created a new JSON file, installed the rollup json plugin, and it built.  Sum total of learning: 0;