# Vite JS output JSON to separate assets folder

Tags: vite, rollupjs

I setup my Vite config to split certain assets files to specific folders.

- assets

  - animations
  - fonts
  - images
  - scripts
  - styles

```
rollupOptions: {
        
        output: {
          assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
            let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.').at(1);
            if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
              extType = 'images';
            } else if (/css|sass|scss/i.test(extType)) {
              extType = 'styles';
            } else if (/woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf/i.test(extType)) {
              extType = 'fonts';
            } else if (/json/.test(extType)) {
              extType = 'animations';
            }
            return `${extType}/[name][extname]`;
          },
          entryFileNames: `scripts/[name].js`,
          chunkFileNames: `scripts/[name].js`,
          sourcemap: true
        }
      },
```

The problem are not JSONs files are not outputted to animations folder. This folder is not created at all.

I setup simple stackblitz to outline my local https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-vs9rej?file=vite.config.js

When I import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
and add json() to plugin I get an error

> [plugin:json] Could not parse JSON file

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`@rollup/plugin-json` converts JSON files into modules, which Vite already supports out of the box, so that plugin is not needed.

Since Vite converts `.json` imports into JavaScript modules (not assets), you won't see those `.json` files in the build output, and the `rollupOptions.output` config you have would not have the desired effect. Instead, you'd see the JSON content of those files in the `.js` bundle.

#### Possible Solution

One way to preserve `animations/*.json` as [static assets](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets) is to move them into `public/` and have your app fetch the files at runtime.

To output the `.json` files to `<BUILD_OUTPUT_DIR>/animations/`, put them in `public/animations/`. The files would then be reachable at runtime from: `<BASE_URL> + '/animations/<FILENAME>.json'`, where `<BASE_URL>` can be replaced with [`import.meta.env.BASE_URL`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-static-assets). For instance, to fetch `animations/act.json` at runtime:

```js
// scripts/_animation.js

fetch(import.meta.env.BASE_URL + '/animations/act.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log('animation', json)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.warn('cannot fetch animation', err)
  });
```

It's unclear how you intend to use those files because your demo does nothing with them after importing, but the above should work in most use cases.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-static-assets)

Comment: yes, placing animation folder with all my JSONs inside public folder has worked. Thank you Tony.